# Run Create-React-App Tests not in Watch Mode

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, create-react-app, githooks

I have a project created using Create-React-App. I am looking to add in a `precommit` hook to run our linter and tests with the `pre-commit` package.

```
"pre-commit": [
  "precommit-msg",
  "lint",
  "test"
],
```

However, since the test script runs by default in watch mode, this prevents the commit from ever actually happening. How can add the tests not in watch move in the pre-commit?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the --watchAll=false parameter.
So for example you can create another script like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test:nowatch": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
}
```

And then run

```js
"pre-commit": [
  "precommit-msg",
  "lint",
  "test:nowatch"
],
```

Comment: RUN npm run test:nowatch

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution for my setup by adding the following script in my `package.json` file.

`"test:nowatch": "CI=true react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",`

```
"pre-commit": [
  "precommit-msg",
  "lint",
  "test:nowatch"
],
```

This came from the following thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2336

Comment: Wouldn't this would break in windows?

Comment: @RohanBagchi Yes, above breaks on windows. However, using git bash on windows a similar script works: `"test:all": "set CI=true&&react-scripts test"`

Answer (score 7):

Cross platform solution for this:

1. Install [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env)
2. Use your test command with such props:
   `"test:nowatch": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom --findRelatedTests"`

Answer (score 6):

Just adding the `CI=true` like this `"test": "CI=true react-scripts test"` worked for me

Comment: this is a very elegant solution, thanks! i just created a .env.test file and put it there, CRA supports dotenv files out of the box so i put it there